# Is it possible to debug Azure Web Apps built with Java?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking for a way to remotely debug Java application running on Azure Web Apps.

The basic problem is that I cannot connect to the remotely running Java Application with my debugger. Debugging requires either an open port in the server side, which your Java application could use to listen for remote debuggers or some other approach. The only approach I have found so far is this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-websites-java-remote-debugging. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

The solution I found tries to connect to https://yourdebuggedsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugSiteExtension/JavaDebugSiteExtension.ashx, but I have found no other references to this path from internet. I'm not sure how the author of the application have guessed that something like this could exist.

I could do the debugging elsewhere too, but it seems that the application behaves much slower when it is executed on Azure Web Apps. It would be interesting to be able to debug it while it's running on Azure.

UPDATE: Here's how I tried to use the solution available in Github (see link above)

```
./DebugSession.sh -p 8000 --server mydebuggedsite.scm.azurewebsites.net  --user "<myusername>" --pass "<mypassword>"
```

The error I'm getting

```
INFO: Trying to establish connection with remote: wss://mydebuggedsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugSiteExtension/JavaDebugSiteExtension.ashx
Jul 22, 2015 8:57:59 AM org.azure.waws.DebugSession startSession
SEVERE: java.lang.Exception: Error communicating with remote. Didn't switch protocols
Jul 22, 2015 8:57:59 AM org.azure.waws.DebugSession Terminate
```

Comment: Which step did you follow?

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT: I just followed the instructions on the in the Github link. I tried to launch debugging session with the following command line 
    ./DebugSession.sh -p 8000 --server mydebuggedsite.scm.azurewebsites.net  --user "<myusername>" --pass "<mypassword>" 

The response I'm getting ends with the following error:
    INFO: Trying to establish connection with remote: wss://mydebuggedsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugSiteExtension/JavaDebugSiteExtension.ashx
    SEVERE: java.lang.Exception: Error communicating with remote. Didn't switch protocols

Comment: I added the errors I received to the original question too. It seems that the comments are not the best place to add copies of log :)

Comment: Please enable Websockets on your azure websites.. The debugsession.sh command line looks correct.

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra WebSockets were enabled. Have you succesfully tried debugging Java application using these instructions? I just wonder are those instructions really correct.

Comment: Could you make it work, @PerttuT? how?

Comment: ow, i just made it. In my case it was a problem with the user and password. Here we dont use in the name of the application (like we do on ftp), just the username.